# Can I use a variable from java file in a scala file?

Tags: java, scala

As the title says, is it possible to use a java variable in a scala file?

Say I have two files, `java1.java` and `scala1.scala` in the same folder.

`java1.java` file,

```
public class java1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Hello";
    }
}
```

`scala1.scala` file,

```
object scala1 extends App {
    val b: String = a // a is the variable from java1.java
}
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948120/creating-a-java-object-in-scala) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589762/is-it-possible-to-import-custom-java-classes-into-scala) should help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is a local variable. It is local to the scope it is defined in, in that case the method `java1.main`. (That's why it's called a "local" variable, after all!)

You cannot even access this variable in a different method of the same file, let alone a completely different object.

This has nothing to do with Scala vs. Java. This is true for pretty much *every* programming language ever created.

Comment: Can I access if it is not a local variable?

Comment: @sachinmb27 I'd suggest you open a new question to ask that, and show exactly what code you have in mind. "is not a local variable" is vague

Comment: Okay. Thanks @SethTisue